# CucumberReportPublisher not working in pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, dsl, cucumber-jvm

I'm using Jenkins Pipeline job to build and run unit test, all my stages written in groovy script, I'm getting below exception while generating the cucumber report:

```
[CucumberReport] Preparing Cucumber Reports
[CucumberReport] Copied 0 json files from workspace "/var/opt/jenkins/data/workspace/myJenkinsJob/${pwd()}/target/cucumber-html-report" to reports directory "/var/opt/jenkins/data/jobs/myJenkinsJob/builds/13/cucumber-html-reports/.cache"


java.lang.IllegalStateException: basedir /myJenkinsJOb/builds/13/cucumber-html-reports/.cache does not exist


    at org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.scan(DirectoryScanner.java:879)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.findJsonFiles(CucumberReportPublisher.java:191)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:139)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:69)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please find my DSL script below:

```
stage "Publish Reports"
echo "***** Publish Reports *****"
def ReportPath = "${pwd()}/target/cucumber-html-report"
def JSONPath = "${pwd()}/target/cucumber-json-report.json"

step([$class: 'CucumberReportPublisher', 
            jsonReportDirectory: '${ReportPath}', 
            fileIncludePattern: '${JSONPath}'])
```

I'm new to DSL script, can someone help what I'm doing wrong here why cucumber report is not getting generated here.

Appreciate your help in advance!

Thanks!

**Note:** We are using the latest cucumber report version

Answer (score 0):

```
stage "Publish Reports"
echo "***** Publish Reports *****"
def ReportPath = "${pwd()}/target/cucumber-html-report"
def JSONPath = "${pwd()}/target/cucumber-reports"

steps.step([$class: 'CucumberReportPublisher', 
        jsonReportDirectory: '${JSONPath}', 
        fileIncludePattern: '*.json'
```

So you have to give json root path in 'jsonReportDirectory' and file pattern should be '.json'

'CucumberReportPublisher' class itself look for all .json files present at jsonReportDirectory